# Swift 5 how to map an array of objects

Tags: swift, react-native

I am trying to remap an array of objects so that I can use the values in a react native callback

manager.swft

```
@objc func getDevices {
  let devices = customManager.endpoints
  print(devices)
}

// prints an array of endpoints like shown below:
// [Endpoint(name: "first", uniqueID: 39), Endpoint(name: "second", uniqueID: 28)]
```

How can I remap the output of devices so that it prints or can be used in a callback like show below

I need devices to print like shown below:

```
[name: "first", uniqueID: 39, name: "second", uniqueID: 28]

or 

[{name: "first", uniqueID: 39}, {name: "second", uniqueID: 28}]
```

Basically I need to print out the array of devices without the "Endpoint" prefixed

Comment: How do you create those `endpoints` in the first place?

Comment: Map what kind of object to what other kind of structure? We need more details than this.

Comment: @Sulthan The endpoints come from a 3rd party package. I just post some code that would show example of the data that I receive from the 3rd part package

Comment: @xTwisteDx The object is an array of objects from a 3rd party package. basically I want to get the object only and remove the part that show Endpoint

Comment: `CustomStringConvertible`? But, usually using the `description` is rarely a good idea... If you reallly need a string like that, add a method to `EndPoint`, like `func customStringForReact() -> String`, and do you own print...

Comment: your question is not at all clear. You say "The endpoints come from a 3rd party package." Ok, what is the type of the `endpoints` variable? Edit your question to include the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Swift [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d) function.

```swift
let devices = customManager.endpoints.map {
  { name: $0.name, uniqueID: $0.uniqueID }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the type of the `endpoints` variable to your question. I gather it is of type `Endpoint`? So edit your question and show us the definition of EndPoint.

Let's say it's a struct:

```
struct Endpoint {
   let Name: String
   let uniqueID: Int
}
```

You could add an extension to the Endpoint type that makes it conform to CustomStringConvertible:

```
extension EndPoint: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "{name: \(name), uniqueID: \(uniqueID)}"
    }
}
```

And then use something like this:

```
let descriptions = customManager.endpoints.map{$0.description}
   .joined(separator: ", ")
print((descriptions)
```